# How to delegate third-party components in react-native ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have following react native component in android.
parent class contains some common settings, 
and some template code (eg. setData).

### android version

parent component

```
public abstract class ParentComponent<T extends Chart, U extends Entry> extends SimpleViewManager {
    @ReactProp(name = "commonSettings")
    public void setCommonSettings(T chart, ReadableMap propMap) {
        // do common settings
    }

    abstract U createEntry(ReadableMap value);

    @ReactProp(name = "data")
    public void setData(Chart chart, ReadableArray values) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values(); i++) {
            chart.addEntry(values.getMap(i));
        }
    }
}
```

child component A

```
public class FooComponent extends ParentComponent<FooChart, FooEntry> {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "FooChart";
   }

    @Override
    protected View createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new FooChart(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "fooSettings")
    public void setFooSettings(FooChart chart, ReadableMap propMap) {
        // do foo settings
    }

    @Override
    FooEntry createEntry(ReadableMap value) {
        return xxxxx;
    }   
}
```

child component B

```
public class BarComponent extends ParentComponent<BarChart, BarEntry> {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "BarChart";
   }

    @Override
    protected View createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new BarChart(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "barSettings")
    public void setBarSettings(FooChart chart, ReadableMap propMap) {
        // do foo settings
    }

    @Override
    BarEntry createEntry(ReadableMap value) {
        return xxxxx;
    }   
}
```

### But How should I implement these in ios?

I am quite new to oc & swift developing, here are my doubts.

- In ios, there need a RCTViewManager that return a UIView instance.
  what shoud be the UIView instance?
  I don't want to inherit FooChart & BarChart, *delegate* is what I need.
  So should I create a custom UIView, initialize a fooChart and holds its reference, then self.addSubView(fooChart) ?
- How to share the common settings and template code? Extension ?
- Do I have to duplicate `RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(commonSettings, NSDictionary)` in both FooChartViewManager and BarChartViewManager?

I tried to define `class ParentComponentManagerSwift: RCTViewManager`,
and declare `RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(commonSettings, NSDictionary)`  there,
and `class FooComponentManagerSwift: ParentComponentManager`, but it doesn't work.
 But our components do inherit bunch of exports like backgroundColor/width/height  which declared in RCTViewManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If FooChart & BarChart is a subclass of UIView, then you can initialize FooChart & BarChart, set delegate and return it directly

```
- (UIView *)view {
  FooChart *chart = [FooChart new];
  chart.delegate = self;
  return chart;
}
```

2) You can share common settings and template code using inheritance

3) You can either duplicate exports or create some macros that will combine common exports.

Components actually do not inherit exports. All components have RCTViewManager exports + own exports, but its done without using inheritance.

Comment: hi，I made an attempt of this, but met a problem at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435599/protocol-extension-doesnt-work-with-rct-export-view-property), can you help me ?